# How to compare elements of an array with a scalar using a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, matlab

I want to simulate Bit error rate (BER) of Pulse Amplitude Modulation (PAM) in Python just like it's done in MATLAB.

I tried to run a loop using ii as an index variable but I get an error saying "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous". I tried googling it but I couldn't understand the answers. I have been coding in MATLAB and I wanna learn Python now. I'm a complete beginner in Python.

```
N = int(1e6); # number of bits
for ii in range(N):
    if data_bits[ii]==1:
        y = sm
```

I get an error with the line data_bits[ii]==1. This does not happen in MATLAB.

NOTE: I'm showing the problematic part. This code may not make complete sense but just highlights what I am having trouble understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You would not use a for loop to begin with. You can simply "select" the correct values and set their value to some other value:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.rand(10,1)
print(arr)

# select all values > 0.5 and set to 5
arr[(arr>0.5)] = 5

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
# random values to begin with
[[0.00859812]
 [0.03146223]
 [0.55717924]
 [0.14131905]
 [0.52429833]
 [0.45643492]
 [0.4409319 ]
 [0.96135169]
 [0.41511691]
 [0.33970605]]

# after selecting and setting to 5
[[0.00859812]
 [0.03146223]
 [5.        ]
 [0.14131905]
 [5.        ]
 [0.45643492]
 [0.4409319 ]
 [5.        ]
 [0.41511691]
 [0.33970605]]
```